# Group BY week in sql sever

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a weekly report that should display weekly count of attendance for a movie.

Example:

```
2016-01-18
2016-01-18
2016-01-18
2016-01-18
2016-01-19
2016-01-19
2016-01-19
2016-01-19
2016-01-20
2016-01-20
2016-01-21
2016-01-21
2016-01-29
2016-01-30
2016-01-30
```

Above is the example where movie show started on 18 th jan and it continuously ran for week 1.
So if i am running the report on 22 nd jan the output should be

```
Week1  12
```

Again the movie has been rescheduled on 29 th and it continuously ran till 30th jan.
So if i am running the report on Feb 1 st 2016 the ouput should be

```
Week1 3
```

Comment: What have you done to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: we have similar situation here but how we do is create a time table to show everyday of the year, it got the week number, holiday flag and some other information about days. using it could help us to check the week window

Comment: How do you define your weeks? I.e. you ran the report on the 22nd January and it apparently encompassed a period from Monday - Thursday. When you run the report on 1st February, it produces a report that looks back to (at least) the previous Friday (29th). I can't even guess at the rules here for taking the current date and deriving which period of time the report should cover

Comment: Week days, and week numbers, are sometimes region specific. Do you want answer according to the ISO standard, or for some specific region?

Comment: The Week what i am considering is from friday to thursday.
I should take min(ShowDate) and that week should show week1 even it is week 3 or watever.

Comment: SELECT 
 
  DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(DATE, SCHEDULE.ShowTime,105))  WeekNo,
  COUNT(TD.TicketDetailID) Attendance, SUM(TD.NettPrice) DayNett

FROM 
  [BoxOffice].[TicketDetail] TD 
  INNER JOIN [BoxOffice].[Ticket] TICKET ON TD.TICKETID = TICKET.TICKETID
  INNER JOIN Common.Movie MOVIE ON Movie.MovieID = TICKET.MovieID
  INNER JOIN Boxoffice.Schedule SCHEDULE ON SCHEDULE.MovieID = Movie.MovieID
WHERE

  MOVIE.movieID ='EE290FC1-7195-40F4-81DC-B42B1224926C'
  AND CONVERT(DATE, SCHEDULE.ShowTime,105) <='02-02-2016'
 GROUP BY
  DATEPART(WEEK, CONVERT(DATE, SCHEDULE.ShowTime,105))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the week() function. It returns the week number for a data. You can use that for grouping (http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-week-function.php).

```
SELECT WEEK(datefield), count
GROUP BY WEEK(datefield)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `count(*)`. You forgot the `FROM tablename` part. What will happen when the table contains data for several years? Besides, OP wants data for "current week".